# How to compute the cutoff frequency of a bandpass audio filter?

Tags: band-pass, cutoff-frequency

Much like the title says, I'm wondering how one would compute the cutoff frequency of a bandpass filter given the filter's specs, rather than the usual resistance and capacitance.  In other words, how would one calculate cutoff frequency given signal bandwidth (including low and high values) sampling rate and the order of the filter, rather than the typical Fc=1/(2piRC)

Comment: Given what specs? A filter is typically specified in terms of cutoff or bandwidth, so the solution seems trivial.

Comment: A bandpass has two cutoff frequencies, a lower one and an upper one. I think how you calculate it depends on what type of filter it is (order pole locations, etc). The upper cutoff is normally the point at which the signal is attenuated by 3 dB compared to the pass band as you move up in frequency from the center of the band. The lower cutoff is the point at which the signal is attenuated by 3 dB compared to the pass band, but on the low side.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to take a step back and explain what you are trying to do or why you are asking this. Then you might get a better answer. Right now I am not sure what you are getting at.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.